# Extension Method not available for enum in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am Trying to use an extension method for enum in WCF.  Here is the class with the extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ComponentModel;
using AttributesHelperExtensionNameSpace;

namespace Ratu
{
    [DataContract]
    public enum StatusCode
    {
        [EnumMember]
        [Description("C")]
        Closed = 0,
        [EnumMember]
        [Description("A")]
        Cancelled = 1
    }
}

namespace AttributesHelperExtensionNameSpace
{
    public static class AttributesHelperExtension
    {
        public static string ToDescription(this Enum value)
        {
            var da = (DescriptionAttribute[])(value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString())).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            return da.Length > 0 ? da[0].Description : value.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Then I attempt to extract the description:

```
StatusCode status = StatusCode.Closed;
string test = status.ToDescription(); // The Error is here
```

But I am geting an error:

```
Ratu.StatusCode does not contain a definition for 'ToDescription' and no extension method 'ToDescription' accepting a first argument of type 'Ratu.StatusCode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Any help to why the ToDescription is not available would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Force the cast again at ((DescriptionAttribute)da[0]).Description

Comment: Are you sure you have `using AttributesHelperExtensionNameSpace;` in the code that tries to use the extension method?  What if you try `AttributesHelperExtension.ToDescription(status)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace for the Extension method
 (AttributesHelperExtensionNameSpace) needs to be added to the using statement where the extension is being used.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you.